# Stop redirecting to login page

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have protected library page by protected route of react router dom using requiredAuth function but it is redirecting to login page if page is refreshed

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.